# How to add a boot message before initializing a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails application. In the main layer I wrap the HTML code of the controllers in `#app`:

```
body
  #app
    = yield
```

Vue components in the HTML (Slim) Rails application code I describe as follows:

```
news-list limit="24"
news-show news-id="528"
```

Vue in the project is globally initialized as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     // ...
})
```

The problem is that sometimes there is a delay before Vue completes the render.

That is, it looks like this:

1. Go to the Rails application page. We see an empty page.
2. Render the Vue component. There is still no news list. General information only.
3. API request takes place. Rendered list of news. Done.

I want to do on the side of a Rails application between 1 and 2 points that something similar to the spinner.

That is, I go to the Rails application page. Wherever there is a Vue component, I see a spinner. The spinner disappears as soon as the component finishes the render.

But I do not know how to do it...

I hope for your help. And sorry for my english.

Comment: doesn't you could render the spinner manually in the html.erb page?

Comment: if you initialize Vue on `'DOMContentLoaded'`, all your components are loaded on every pages (except if you're using async components), meaning there's no delay between your 1 and 2 points. Then waiting for API calls is between 2 and 3 points and a spinner can be handled by Vue

Answer (score 0):

Showing spinner before vue component is initialized can be done by rendering spinner inside element that vue is being initialized on.

```
<div id="app">
   <!-- This content will be replaced, once the Vue component is rendered -->
</div>
```

Spinner after component is loaded can be done using `v-if`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <spinner v-if='!news' />
    <list-of-news v-else :news='news' />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Read my question again, please. I understand that my English is terrible, but still the information about 1, 2 and 3 points is more than understandable.

Comment: If you render anything inside `#app` it will be replaced when vue component is initialized. So you can render spinner there. Maybe I still do not understand question. Thought you wanted something on a page before `new Vue({` is executed.

Comment: This answers the question, IMHO. The problem is maybe that the OP confuses the "app-component" with the other component?